# Some vectorlike overset

Tags: accents

Is there some method to write the following ? [image]

I have searched a lot but couldnt find anything.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://goo.gl/z69vm) Do you want to achieve this in math mode?

Comment: Related/duplicate: [How to look up a symbol or identify a math alphabet?](http://goo.gl/NjJCc)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using MnSymbol, you can access it using `\overlinesegment{abc}`, as you can see

[image]

Here is the list of symbols: [from CTAN](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf).

Comment: Thanks. I get the following error "! LaTeX Error: File `MnSymbol.sty' not found.". A first glance on google results gives me the impression that many other people get the same error. Is there some easy way to fix this ?

Comment: You have to install that package http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mnsymbol

Comment: The usual caveat applies: `MnSymbol` changes *all* the math symbols.

Answer (score 3):

These are made from scratch, so there is no worry of changing other math symbols.  The rule thickness is governed by length `\thk`, while the vertical height of the end bars is dictated by `\rlht`.  The macro `\overlinesegment`, in addition to its mandatory argument takes an optional argument to define the stacking gap.  That stacking gap can be defined as relative to the top of the characters (`\def\stacktype{S}`) or relative to the baseline (`\def\stacktype{L}`).  The default stacking gap can be defined using the methods intrinsic to the `stackengine` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}[2013-10-15]
\usepackage{calc}
\newlength\thk
\newlength\rlht
\setlength\thk{1pt}
\setlength\rlht{1ex}
\def\vrl{\rule[-.5\rlht+.5\thk]{\thk}{\rlht}}
\newcommand\overlinesegment[2][\stackgap]{%
  \stackon[#1]{#2}{\vrl\rule{\widthof{#2}}{\thk}\vrl}
}
\parskip 1ex
\begin{document}
Vary overheight with optional argument:
\overlinesegment{abc} \overlinesegment[1pt]{abc}

placed relative to top of text
\overlinesegment{PdQ} \overlinesegment{anw}

placed relative to baseline\def\stacktype{L}
\overlinesegment{PdQ} \overlinesegment{anw}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. How can I install this package (stackengine) ? I downloaded it from CTAN but dont know where to copy the files.

Comment: @A.S.  Initially, you can just place the .sty file in your current directory.  Where it resides permanently depends on your TeX installation.  For MikTex,for example, the default package directory is `C:\Users\[your name]\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex`.  Once placed in the proper location, you typically have to update your package database to complete the installation.